# Play swf file on webpage

Tags: asp.net, flash

Hey guys I am trying to play a .swf file on my web page I have already tried to embed it using HTML and it works. But is there anyway of playing a .swf file after button click event in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Before you get to carried away with using flash could I urge you to read this http://occupyflash.org/ and then invest a little of your time researching html5 (specifically canvas) :)... http://www.williammalone.com/articles/flash-vs-html5-canvas-drawing/ and this http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tutorials/a/canvas-vs-svg-vs-flash.htm will give you a good start.

### Edit

Without seeing your current code I can't give a precise answer but this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src='insert-route-to.swf' id='insert-id-here' controls>
      Your browser does not support HTML5 videos please Upgrade.
    </video>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('insert-id-here').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('insert-id-here').pause()">Pause</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the links and information, but I still want to know if there is a possible way of playing a swf file after a button click event.

Comment: ?Any help?  Common courtesy to give people feedback on this website.

Answer (score 0):

on button click

```
Response.redirect("file path");
```

something like:

```
Response.redirect("Video/abc.swf");
```

where "`Video`" is folder name which is present in project folder and "`abc`" is file name.